# Save Form Array Data at Once into Database in AspnetCore MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to get to save a form with many rows at once.If it is just one single row, I am able to insert into DB successfully, but having challenge reading a form array and storing it to the Database. 
**The View:**

```
<tbody>
    @{int c = 0;
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            c++;

            <tr>
                <td>@c</td>
                <td>@item.FltNo<input type="hidden" name="FltNo[@c]" value="@item.FltNo"/></td>
                <td>@item.FleetModelName<input type="hidden" name="Fltmodel[@c]" value="@item.FleetModelName"/></td>
                <td>@item.EngineName<input type="hidden" name="Engine[@c]" value="@item.EngineName"/></td>
                <td>@item.LocationName<input type="hidden" name="Location[@c]" value="@item.LocationName"/></td>
                <td>@item.ServiceType<input type="hidden" name="ServiceType[@c]" value="@item.ServiceType"/></td>
                <td>@item.ServiceSequence<input type="hidden" name="NextSvr[@c]" value="@item.ServiceSequence"/></td>

            </tr>
        }
    }
```

**The Controller**

```
public IActionResult Create(string ButtonClicked, Mrptran trans)
        {
    if (ButtonClicked == "GenerateBtn")
                {


                        var mrpData = new Mrptran
                        {
                            FltNo = trans.FltNo,
                            Fltmodel = trans.Fltmodel,
                            Engine = trans.Engine,
                            Location = trans.Location,
                            ServiceType = trans.ServiceType,
                            NextSvr = trans.NextSvr,
                            CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name,
                            CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
                          };

                        _context.Mrptrans.Add(mrpData);
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                    }
}
```

Question: How do I read the form array to the Database once. I am using Entity-Framework.Any Suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After Serveral Troubleshooting and looking at Stalkoverflow again and again, I was able to figure it out and so, decide to post it ,perhaps to help someone, someday.
1. I added an hidden field in the View to keep track of the Total Row.
2. I modified the Save Action method to loop over the Total Row, while saving it to DB. This works, but if there is a better way, it will be appreciated.

**The Updated View**

```
 <input type="hidden" name="TotalRecord" value="@Model.Count()" />
     foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    c++;

                    <tr>
                        <td>@c</td>
                        <td>@item.FltNo<input type="hidden" name="FltNo[@c]" value="@item.FltNo" /></td>
                        <td>@item.FleetModelName<input type="hidden" name="Fltmodel[@c]" value="@item.FleetModelName" /></td>
                        <td>@item.EngineName<input type="hidden" name="Engine[@c]" value="@item.EngineName" /></td>
                        <td>@item.LocationName<input type="hidden" name="Location[@c]" value="@item.LocationName" /></td>
                        <td>@item.ServiceType<input type="hidden" name="ServiceType[@c]" value="@item.ServiceType" /></td>
                        <td>@item.ServiceSequence<input type="hidden" name="NextSvr[@c]" value="@item.ServiceSequence" /></td>
    </tr>
                    }

                }
            </tbody>
```

**The Controller**

```
 public IActionResult Create(Mrptran trans, int? TotalRecord)
        {
  for(int i = 1; i <=TotalRecord; i++)
                {
                 var mrpData = new Mrptran
                    {
                        FltNo = Request.Form["FltNo["+i+"]"],
                        CostUnit = Request.Form["CostUnit[" + i+"]"],
                        CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name,
                        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
                        Engine = Request.Form["Engine[" + i+"]"],
                        Fltmodel = Request.Form["Fltmodel[" + i + "]"],
                        Location = Request.Form["Location[" + i + "]"],
                        PartNo = Request.Form["PartNo[" + i + "]"],
                        Mtypes = "S",
                        NextSvr = Request.Form["NextSvr[" + i + "]"],
 };

                    _context.Mrptrans.Add(mrpData);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
```

}